# Advice on wrapping third party libraries

Tags: c++, c, api

I have been working a year now as a software developer for a at the computer-vision department of a company. My main job is integration of third-party software into a framework, so i usually end up writing wrapper libraries because a lot of this third party software does not work the way we want it to work(not thread safe, pain in the a** to use etc.).

Normally i just wrap the whole library and guard the calls to the library with mutual exclusions(thread safety is somehow the major problem with most extern libraries). I really enjoy doing this, as it puts you into a lot of interesting situations and you get to see a lot of interesting code. However i often think that i am not doing it properly or that my implementation is not really good. I feel like i am lacking some sort of design knowledge on how to properly do stuff like that.

Basically i want to know if there are any good guidelines or hints about designing a proper 'API ontop of broken API', or if this is always bound to be quite hackish and ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I will quote an answer to another question on here the other day**:

1. Does your current method pass testing?
2. Is it fast enough?

If yes, keep doing what you are doing.

**As an alternative**

Just ensure your new API encompasses both the **intended** functionality and the **conventional** or **accidental** functionality of the original. Also ensure it presents a 'fit-for-purpose' re-presentation. Take a peek at the C++ wrapping of C libraries in FOSS projects such as GTK/GTK for C++ (which just wraps the former).

If the API is broken, fix it and submit a patch ... get involved with the third-parties (I am assuming having access to the source means they won't mind this) ... You could re-write some of their API to be 'wrapping friendly' and suggest they merge some changes. If there is a problem, be the one to fix it.

Not much to it, just wrap A with B and ensure B does what A was supposed to, or is used for.

Comment: Thank you, that somehow boosted my confidence ;)

I usually don't run into any speed or semantic problems but usually the code is just not as clean as i want it to be. but i guess there is no other way around it as i don't have the source of the third-party library.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that I can add to [Aiden's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994139/advice-on-wrapping-third-party-libraries/994186#994186) is that you should also look to replace code that requires explicit initialization and termination with [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) techniques. When I've been faced with providing a façade over APIs, I always seem to run into a class that looks like:

```
struct ADVERTISER {
    /* a bunch of members here */
};

void adv_Initialize(ADVERTISER *adv, /* a bunch of arguments */);
void adv_DoStuff(ADVERTISER *adv);
void adv_Terminate(ADVERTISER *adv);
```

I've seen this wrapped in a C++ class in the following manner:

```
namespace wrapper {
  class Advertiser {
  public:
      Advertiser(): inited_(false) {}
      void initialize(/* a bunch of arguments */) {
        terminate();
        adv_Initialize(&adv_, ...);
        inited_ = true;
      }
      void doStuff() {
        validate();
        adv_DoStuff(&adv_);
      }
      void terminate() {
        if (inited_) {
            adv_Terminate(&adv_);
            inited_ = false;
        }
      }
  protected:
      void validate() {
        if (!inited_) {
            throw std::runtime_error("instance is not valid");
        }
      }
  private:
      ADVERTISER adv_;
      bool inited_;
  };
}
```

The problem is that the `Advertiser` class doesn't really make the API any easier to use or even *cleaner* IMHO. If you run into cases like this, then:

1. Use a fully parameterized constructor to ensure that invalid instances do not exist
2. Clean up all resources in the destructor
3. Write a copy constructor and assignment operator if they make sense **or** make them private and don't implement them.

My goal is to make sure that whatever API I am presenting/creating/wrapping works with our existing coding style. I also try to bend the API into a more OO style than it may currently  be in. I have seen a number of what I call *object-oriented C* like the one that I presented above. If you want to make them really fit into C++, then make then truly object-oriented and take advantage of what C++ gives you:

- Be careful to manage any state variables.
- If actions like copying don't make sense, then hide them.
- If there is any possibility of leaking resources, then find some way to prevent it from happening (usually employing RAII helps).
- Restrict the creation of instances using constructors to eliminate invalid instances and other edge cases.

Comment: Thank you, i think this is some very good advice especially for me as i have a strong C background so i am fairly new to C++.

Comment: You are quite welcome. I spent a bunch of years doing C on embedded platforms before switching to C++ so I can definitely understand. I've found that it makes a huge difference if you make your wrappers fit into C++ better - this way you are gaining something by wrapping the other API.